# Inheritance in c# and object creation in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have classes as follow one is `SuperClass` which is inherited by `ChildClass` and `Child1Class`
[image: ScreenShot]

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public new int Superclassprop = 2;
    public virtual void play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SuperClass");
    }

}

public class ChildClass : SuperClass
{
    public new int Childclassprop = 2;

    public override void play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ChildClass");
    }

}
public class Child1Class : SuperClass
{
    public new int Childclassprop = 3;

    public override void play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child1Class");
    }
}
```

Now when i create an object something like below i don't understand what is the difference between these. i had read a huge bunch of blogs related to this but i didn't find any justifiable answer please help me to understand what actually is happening here or suggest me a good blog or article including on SO where i can understand a whole concept behind this why we need this where the actual real time use of these concept?

```
SuperClass obj = new SuperClass();
SuperClass obj1 = new ChildClass();
```

I have attached screenshot of watch which is generating on Run-Time why there is a `obj1` consisting all properties but i can access only `SuperClassprop`?

Thanks in advance any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to research the difference between compile time and run time type for an object reference.

Comment: Try calling `obj.play()` and `obj1.play()` and compare the output.

Comment: I recommend reading up on [Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx), [Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx), and [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

Comment: This is too broad. We specialize in specific questions, explaining a whole *concept* is better done through books or other tutorials.

Comment: Please see my updated question i have attached screenshot as well

Comment: Your question is very different now, now you're asking why you can't access the properties of a derived class. Remember at compile time, the compiler doesn't know what kind of object will go into `obj1` so will only show you the methods on the base class. If you want to access the child properties, then cast it to the relevant type.

Comment: @Curiousdev I edited my answer, tried to fit it to your updated question

Comment: My recommendation is to get a commonly accepted book (C# in a Nutshell will do) and read the relevant sections. Blogs and online articles are generally not vetted; it's easy to find bad ones, especially on basic topics. (People who write on advanced topics more often know what they are talking about, in my experience.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the more practical example of your topic:

```
using System;

 public class Music
    {
        public virtual string play()
        {
            return "Play Music";
        }
    }

    public class Drum : Music
    {
        public override string play()
        {
            return "Play Drums";
        }
    }

    public class Piano : Music
    {
        public override string play()
        {
            return "Play Piano";
        }
    }

    public class PlayMusicService
    {
        private readonly Music _musicContext;
        public PlayMusicService(Music musicContext)
        {
            this._musicContext = musicContext;
        }

        public string PlayAlbum()
        {
            return _musicContext.play();
        }        
    }


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string whatPlayed = "";

        Drum drums = new Drum();        
        PlayMusicService music1 = new PlayMusicService(new Drum());     
        whatPlayed = music1.PlayAlbum();
        Console.WriteLine(whatPlayed);

        Piano piano = new Piano();
        PlayMusicService music2 = new PlayMusicService(new Piano());
        whatPlayed = music2.PlayAlbum();
        Console.WriteLine(whatPlayed);
    }
}
```

**Output:** 
Play Drums
Play Piano

Answer (score 3):

> i don't understand what is the difference between these.

One of the main differences is the constructor call

```
SuperClass obj = new SuperClass();
SuperClass obj1 = new ChildClass();
```

In the case of `obj1` the `ChildClass` constructor is called after the `SuperClass` constructor and the field and property initialisation is done also for the property `Childclassprop`

> consisting all properties but i can access only SuperClassprop?

The variable `obj1` is still of type `SuperClassprop` so at compile time you are only allowed to see and use those variables that belong to this class. If you want to actually access the variables of `ChildClass` you will have to cast it to the proper type:

```
var r = (obj1 as ChildClass).Childclassproput;
```

> why we need this where the actual real time use of these concept?

One scenario that comes to my mind is : it might be that at compile time it is not clear which class has to be instantiated. But this is decided at runtime. But you need already a variable to write the call of the specific `play()` method. At runtime it will be decided which method is called in the end.

```
SuperClass obj = new SuperClass();

bool condition = false;
if (condition)
{
    obj = new ChildClass();
}
else
{
    obj = new ChildClass1();
}

// now just call the method and the proper method will be called
obj.play();
```